# Flask and best way to reduce mysql queries, maybe celery?

Tags: python, flask, celery

After i researched for three days and played with redis and celery i m no longer sure what the right solution to my problem is.

Its a simple problem. I have a simple flask app returning the data of a mysql query. But i dont want to query the database for every request made, as they might be 100 requests in a second. I wanna setup a daemon that queries independently my database every five seconds and if someone makes a request it should return the data of the previous request and when those 5 secs pass it will return the data from the latest query. All users recieve the same data. Is CELERY the solution?

i researched for three days.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [Flask-Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)]

Just set a cache timeout of 5 seconds on your view and it will return a cached view response containing the result of the query made the first time and for all other query in the next 5 secs. When time is out, the first request will regenerate the cache by doing the query and all the flow of your view.

If your view function use arguments, use memoization instead of cache decorator to let caching use your arguments to generate the cache. For exemple, if you want to return a page details and you don't use memoization, you will return the same page detail for all your user, no matter of the id / slug in arguments.

The documentation of Flask-Caching explain everything better than me

Comment: @JackJones You're welcome. If it's the solution for your need, please check this answer has a good one